# Return a struct directly or fill a pointer?

Tags: c

Let's say I have the following function to initialize a data structure:

```
void init_data(struct data *d) {
        d->x = 5;
        d->y = 10;
}
```

However, with the following code:

```
struct data init_data(void) {
        struct data d = { 5, 10 };
        return d;
}
```

Wouldn't this be optimized away due to copy elision and be just as performant as the former version?

I tried to do some tests on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,lang:___c,source:'struct+data+%7B%0A++++int+x%3B%0A++++int+y%3B%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Avoid+init_data(struct+data+*d)+%7B%0A++++++++d-%3Ex+%3D+5%3B%0A++++++++d-%3Ey+%3D+10%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Astruct+data+init_data_2()+%7B%0A++++++++struct+data+d+%3D+%7B+5,+10+%7D%3B%0A++++++++return+d%3B%0A%7D'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C+source+%231',t:'0')),k:50,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:cg73,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'1',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'1',trim:'1'),lang:___c,libs:!(),options:'-O3',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+gcc+7.3+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C',t:'0')),header:(),k:50,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4) to see if the assembly was the same, but when using any optimization flags everything was always entirely optimized away, with nothing left but something like this: `movabsq $42949672965, %rax`, and I am not sure if the same would happen in real code.

The first version I provided seems to be very common in C libraries, and I do not understand why as they should be both just as fast with RVO, with the latter requiring less code.

Comment: Copy elision is a C++ feature, but C compilers are usually free to do whatever they like, as long as the (single threaded) end result remains the same.

Comment: `movabsq $42949672965, %rax` is `movabsq $0xA00000005, %rax`. Your entire eight-byte `struct` is entirely contained in `%rax`, with 10 in the high 32 bits and 5 in the low 32 bits. So, for small structures, in the C implementation you are using, returning a structure may be more efficient than passing a pointer to space to write the result, since the former returns data in a register, whereas the latter has to write it to the pointed-to memory. However, these sorts of things are fragile, so you should first write clear code and worry about optimization only in the most critical code.

Comment: @EricPostpischil What if the actual size of my structure is `16` bytes on 32 bit, and `32` bytes on 64 bit, would the result be the same?

Comment: At least create the struct using parameters (i.e. `struct data init_data(int x, int y)`), otherwise it's pointless to reason about it because the compiler will just use a constant. In actual code, both functions might simply be inlined and produce the same assembly. If you want to prevent inlining for testing purposes, add `__attribute__((noinline))` before each function and call them from other functions which *use the struct afterwards* (to prevent the compiler from optimizing away everything).

Comment: On the other hand, stopping the compiler from optimizing the code just to see it will not tell what it would look like in a real program. See [The Streetlight effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Streetlight_effect)

Answer (score 0):

> *The first version I provided seems to be very common in C libraries, and I do not understand why as they should be both just as fast with
>   RVO, with the latter requiring less code.*

The main reason for the first being so common is historic.  The second way of initializing structures from literals was not standard (well, it was, but only for `static` initializers and never for automatic variables) and it's never allowed on assignments (well, I've not checked the status of the recent standards)  Even, in ancient C, a simple assignment as:

```
 struct A a, b;

 ...

 a = b;  /* this was not allowed a long time ago */
```

was not accepted at all.

So, in order to be able to compile code in every platform, you have to write the old way, as normally, modern compilers allow you to compile legacy code, while the opposite (old compilers accepting new code) is not possible.

And this also applies to returning structures or passing them by value.  Apart of being normally a huge waste of resources (it's common to see the whole structure being copied in the stack or copied back to the proper place, once the function returns) old compilers didn't accept these, so to be portable, you must avoid to use these constructs.

Finally a comment:  don't use your compiler to check if both constructs generate the same code, as probably it does... but you'll get the wrong assumption that this is common, and you'll run into error.  Another different implementation can (and is allowed to do) different translation and result in different code.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by `ancient C`. When compiling my second solution with `gcc` and `clang` using the flags `-ansi -Wall -Wextra -pedantic`, it compiled without error or warning. And honestly, supporting anything older than pure `ANSI C` is pointless.

Comment: I mean pre-ansi C, what is known as K&R (Kernighan and Ritchie) C.  The thing is that the language conserves many legacy issues just to be able to compile old code.  I don't mean pre-ansi is good... but compilers have to support it.  and this makes compiler (and language evolution) sometimes a pain.

Comment: I am fairly certain no serious projects use `pre-ansi C`, trying to support it is a waste of time.